# Why does this code return an "NoMethodError in Authors#new" error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following [this tutorial](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html) (authentication section)  and I encountered this error when trying to access localhost:3000/authors/new

```
    views/authors/_form.html.erb where line #2 raised:

    undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #2):

<%= form_with(model: author, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if author.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(author.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this author from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
```

The error appeared when I added the before_filter and zero_authors_or_authenticated method in my authors_controller file.

```
class AuthorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_author, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :zero_authors_or_authenticated, only: [:new, :create]

  def zero_authors_or_authenticated
    unless Author.count == 0 || current_user
      redirect_to root_path
      return false
    end
  end

  # GET /authors
  # GET /authors.json
  def index
    @authors = Author.all
  end

  # GET /authors/1
  # GET /authors/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /authors/new
  def new
    @author = Author.new
  end

  # GET /authors/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /authors
  # POST /authors.json
  def create
    @author = Author.new(author_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @author.save
        format.html { redirect_to @author, notice: 'Author was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @author }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @author.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /authors/1
  # PATCH/PUT /authors/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @author.update(author_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @author, notice: 'Author was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @author }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @author.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /authors/1
  # DELETE /authors/1.json
  def destroy
    @author.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to authors_url, notice: 'Author was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_author
      @author = Author.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def author_params
      params.require(:author).permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end




end
```

Here is the whole views/authors/_form.html.erb if needed

```
<%= form_with(model: author, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if author.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(author.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this author from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% author.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :username %>
    <%= form.text_field :username %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :email %>
    <%= form.text_field :email %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :password %>
    <%= form.text_field :password %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= form.text_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I tried moving the before_filter part further down but then it just does nothing and I looked through for any spelling errors as far as I can tell.

*authors/new.html.erb*

```
    <h1>New Author</h1>

    <%= render 'form', author: @author %>

    <%= link_to 'Back', authors_path %>
```

Full trace from the error message

```
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:45:in `block in capture'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:209:in `with_output_buffer'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:45:in `capture'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:755:in `form_with'
app/views/authors/_form.html.erb:1
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/base.rb:274:in `_run'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:185:in `block in render'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:182:in `instrument'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:386:in `instrument_render_template'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:183:in `render'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:358:in `block in render_partial'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:89:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `instrument'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:88:in `instrument'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:347:in `render_partial'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:317:in `render'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:65:in `render_partial_to_object'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:53:in `render_partial'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:38:in `render'
app/views/authors/new.html.erb:3
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/base.rb:274:in `_run'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:185:in `block in render'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:182:in `instrument'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:386:in `instrument_render_template'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:183:in `render'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:89:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `instrument'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:88:in `instrument'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:58:in `block in render_template'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:66:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:57:in `render_template'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:13:in `render'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:61:in `render_template_to_object'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:29:in `render_to_object'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:118:in `block in _render_template'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/base.rb:304:in `in_rendering_context'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:117:in `_render_template'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:142:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:in `render'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:14:in `block in ms'
/home/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:14:in `ms'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:85:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:34:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:35:in `default_render'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:196:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:135:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:33:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `instrument'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:191:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:252:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:51:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:49:in `block in serve'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:837:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:648:in `call'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:567:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:32:in `call'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:83:in `call'
webpacker (4.2.2) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:23:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.5) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:526:in `call'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:681:in `handle_request'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: You probably don't pass `author` variable to `form` partial. Show the code responsible for `form` partial rendering.

Comment: `<h1>New Author</h1>

<%= render 'form', author: @author %>

<%= link_to 'Back', authors_path %>`   Do you mean this from authors/new.html.erb?

Comment: Ok, you do it properly, there's something else wrong here, I'm not sure what at the moment. What does the log say before the error happens? Are you sure you call `new` action?

Comment: CAn you post the stack trace from your consoler or the page when it errors

Comment: `before_filter` is also depreciated - use `before_action`. Can you show us the logs? Could it be that `zero_authors_or_authenticated` is redirecting the user to the index action and you're trying to render the form there as well?

Comment: I posted the trace. The logs in console show the same thing the error message shows(that I posted in the start). I notice I get a similar error when I go to authors index page 

` undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

<tbody>
    <% @authors.each do |author| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= author.username %></td>
        <td><%= author.email %></td>`

I also tried to put it in the private area but then the filter just doesn't get applied.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change before_filter to before_action, in case anyone runs into this too.